# How to use offset columns bootstrap in a div with display: table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need that my text is centered in my div, vertically, and that div stay horizontally centered, by bootstrap offset-column. But when put diplay: cell in this, is stay align to left.

How to solve it?

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="start">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 start_expression">
        <p class="lead1 start_expression_text">Nunc porta, ipsum vitae faucibus aliquam, justo leo rhoncus sapien.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

my css code:

```
.start_expression { height:222px; display: table;  background: green;}
.start_expression_text {height: 222px; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background: green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the content you wish to have horizontally centered just text?

Use `text-align: center;`